# Python dict to variable with parameter

Tags: python

I have following dict that I reuse a lot in my code:

```
    data[day] = {
        "time": 0,
        "total": 0,
        "date": day,
    }
```

How can I make this dict a variable and reuse it. And set the day when by current day when running the dict.

Comment: If you make this dictionary a variable, this will propagate changes throughout the values, is this want you want?

Comment: yes indeed. It's used in different if's and data changes

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you could use a function:

```
days = ['monday', 'tuesday']


def default(d):
    return {"time": 0, "total": 0, "date": d}


data = {}
for day in days:
    data[day] = default(day)

print(data)
```

**Output**

```
{'monday': {'time': 0, 'total': 0, 'date': 'monday'}, 'tuesday': {'time': 0, 'total': 0, 'date': 'tuesday'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DEFAULT = {
    'time': 0,
    'total': 0 
}

def get_my_dict(day):
    return {**DEFAULT, 'date': day}
```

---

use like:

```
data[day] = get_my_dict(day)
```

Comment: only valid if `day` is a variable, else it has to be quoted like `data["day"]. Also I guess this isn't the answer to the question.

Comment: @zypro I hope now is better